# What event fires to an firefox extension when the back button is selected or history item is selected

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

My extension needs to know that the tab is displaying something from the history rather than the latest loaded document.

onload doesn't seem to be the right event. It doesn't always fire.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [pageshow](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Using_Firefox_1.5_caching#pageshow_event) event, it fires after the onload event and has a parameter called **persisted** that will be set to true when the page is loaded from the cache.